# Is there a standard date/time format that can be passed on a URL?

Tags: .net, datetime, url

Looking at the [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) documentation, it appears that all the standard formats have colons in them, which makes passing them on a url unpleasant/impossible.

Is there a standardized format for passing a datetime on a url, preferably one that can be automatically parsed by .NET?

---

**Update:** A little clarification

The consumer of this data is going to be web service of some kind - it'll either be a simple HTTP GET with this value in the querystring, or it'll be REST with the value in the url somewhere.

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) governs date/time formatting, and according to the wiki article, using `ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")` should be standards-compliant at least. Unfortunately, it doesn't get picked up automatically by ASP.NET MVC (haven't tried anything else yet). For what it's worth, ASP.NET MVC won't automatically convert ticks to a datetime either, which surprised me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll put everything together into one answer:

You could do something like this:

```
        string urlSafeDateString = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToCharArray());

        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(new string(HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(urlSafeDateString)), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLocalTime();
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
        string urlSafeDateString = date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(urlSafeDateString, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm using for now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. ISO 8601

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Just make sure you URLEncode it to deal with the colons.

Comment: I get an `HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST` when I use UrlEncode, and also if I do it twice.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not part of any standard or anything like that, but you could always use a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) as those only contain digits. See [this article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx) for ways to convert it to a .NET DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across this same problem and solved it with the following helper method:

```
    private string Encode(DateTime date)
    {
        var formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return WebUtility.UrlEncode(formattedDate);
    }
```

After using the output in a URL query parameter the value gets correctly deserialised by .NET into DateTime objects passed into my Web API Service.

Answer (score 2):

We actually have a reporting solution where dates and times can be passed in as plain text `CCYYMMDD` and `hhmmss` values then, when the code needs to do anything to those values, it simply uses string operations to turn them back into a format that can be displayed or easily parsed (such as the DB2 ISO formats CCYY-MM-DD or hh.mm.ss).

The result is readable and I'd be surprised if .NET didn't have string manipulation instructions that could do this easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
[HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)
and 
[HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

Comment: The static class is `HttpUtility`, and it would be `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, not html encoding for a url...

Answer (score 1):

If you need the date and time, I would use [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).

If you only need the date, use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(date.ToShortDateString())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

Update: Rick Strahl has discussed this issue before and has offered a solution on [his blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx).

Comment: Be sure to use the InvariantCulture (on both client and server) or this will work/fail at random for different users!

Answer (score 1):

> For what it's worth, ASP.NET MVC won't automatically convert ticks to a datetime either, which surprised me.

There's a constructor for DateTime that takes the number of ticks:

```
 DateTime d = new DateTime(634028202671420663);
```

There's also an override that lets you map that to either local or UTC time.  It's all in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime.aspx

**Edit:** realised from the wording of the post that perhaps you're talking about ASP converting the ticks automatically to a DateTime, rather than having to read the numeric parameter.  Perhaps! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to find a format that would work automatically (for use with model binding)