# How should a RESTful GET resource accept a date-time argument?

Tags: javascript, python, rest, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a standard date/time format that can be passed on a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344987/is-there-a-standard-date-time-format-that-can-be-passed-on-a-url)

What is a good way for a RESTful resource to accept a datetime object? Specifically, I'm not sure what is a good way to represent the date and time as a query argument in the URL.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
GET /Calls?start=YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS
```

I'm using Javascript/jQuery on the Client and Python on the back end, so ideally it would be a format that could easily be written in Javascript and read in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: See this Question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344987/is-there-a-standard-date-time-format-that-can-be-passed-on-a-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to encode the time argument as a string. It's readable for humans and supported by tons of libraries across many languages.

I'd recommend against using Unix time. Your sysadmins will thank you when they're asked to crawl or parse your web server logs for API calls. Using ISO 8601 will avoid them having to build a secondary step into that process to convert the Unix time number into something that actual humans have to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Most datetime libraries (definitely both Python and JS) follow the same formatting approach, namely format strings. I'd go with any one that just uses digits, and uses descending order of size, i.e. YYYYMMDDhhmmss.

The one other thing to consider before jumping into a format is whether you might need to parameterize by something more akin to a date range, and if including the seconds, minutes, hours, etc. might over-specify the request and make it hard for the client to locate the data they are looking for.

Comment: +1. You might want to consider a simple ISO date format library, which should be able to transparently handle variations like "2012062716" (no minutes or seconds, so it's 16:00:00), "20120627161523.127892" (fractional seconds), "2012-06-27 16:15:23" (optional separators), "2012-06-27T16:15:23Z" (separators and timezone specifier), etc., which is nice for debugging purposes. But if you don't need that flexibility, just hardcoding strptime and strftime with '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

unix time... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 1):

why not just `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` ?

As long as both sides can follow this format, I don't see any problem